# On button click fill next picture box

Tags: vb.net, variables, picturebox

I'm writing a little program in VB and I'm stuck at a point where I want to add a specific image on a button click to a picturebox. The tricky part for me is, that each time I click the button, I want the image (from same location, e.g "C:\Test.jpg") to appear in the next picture box.

I tried to use a variable in the picturebox name and increase it on each click but it kept giving errors (must have used it wrong, obviously).

So to make it more clear:

I click Button1

image from location "C:\Test.jpg" appears in PictureBox1

I click Button1 again

image from location "C:\Test.jpg" appears in PictureBox2
etc.

As you can imagine, I'm not an expert in VB.NET so if you good people have any suggestions, thank you in advance :D

Vahur

Comment: Please describe the errors you're getting in detail, and show us what code you're attaching to the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach using Controls.Find():

```
Public Class Form1

    Private counter As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        counter = counter + 1
        Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find("PictureBox" & counter, True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is PictureBox Then
            Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(matches(0), PictureBox)
            Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream("C:\Test.jpg", IO.FileMode.Open)
                pb.Image = New Bitmap(Image.FromStream(fs))
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for my app exactly the way I hoped. Nice :D

Answer (score 0):

Form level:

```
Private mPList As New List(of PictureBox)
Private pIndex as Integer = 0
```

Form Shown:

```
With mPlist
   .Add(PictureBox1)
   .Add(PictureBox2)
   ... continue as needed
Ens With
```

Button Click

```
 ' remove image from last picbox (????)
 mPlist(pIndex).Image = Nothing
 pIndex += 1
 if pIndex > mPlist.Count-1 then pIndex = 0
 mPlist(pIndex).Image.FromFile(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue, I'm sure, is that you are trying to figure out how to increment a number and get a handle of the picture box to set the picture on.  I am going to make a couple assumptions here, in that you are making a card game and you will have a set number of players.  You have a couple options:

For the number, you can either set a PRIVATE variable in your form for holding the next number and on each button click, increment it by 1.

```
Private Player1NextImage as byte = 1
Private Player2NextImage as byte = 1
Private Player3NextImage as byte = 1
Private Player4NextImage as byte = 1
```

In the button click, for the specific player, you would want to get their picturebox that is next:

You can either keep the list of pictureboxes in a list, as show by @Plutonix, or you can just use a SELECT CASE statement and hardcode the pictureboxes.

```
Select Case Player1NextImage
  Case 1
    Player1Card1PictureBox.Image = ...
  Case 2
    Player1Card2PictureBox.Image = ...
Etc...
'Then increment the number
Player1NextImage += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. Let's say your variable is called Counter, and (assuming) that the parent of your pictureboxes is the main form / control, add this to your button click event:

```
    Counter += 1

    Dim Pic As PictureBox = CType(Me.Controls("PictureBox" & Counter.ToString), PictureBox)

    If Pic Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Could not find PictureBox")
    Else
        Pic.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Test.jpg")
    End If
```